# Linear Combination of functions resulting in a function with different end conditions

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, linear-algebra

I have a set of 8 functions (I have stored it in a list called `beammodes`). I am multiplying these functions with a set of 8 scalar values (I have stored it in a list called `kk`) and add them together. The resulting function is way different from the functions present in the set. The way different I mentioned is in the end condition. All the functions in my $f_i(x=0)=0$ and $f_i(x=L)=0$. But the resulting function is not satisfying these end conditions. How it is possible? How the linear combination yields such a result?

```
ClearAll["Global`*"];
Clear[b]

(*properties of beam*)
Y = 2*^11;
ρ = 7850;
aa = 0.1*0.1;
Iyy = 0.1^4/12;
L1 = 4;

(*properties of bar *)
γ = 2.305*L1;

(*Location of the bar *)
z[1] = 1.5;
z[2] = 3;

(*Number of bars*)
n = 2; 

W[1] = c[1]*Sin[b*x1] + c[2]*Cos[b*x1] + c[3]*Sinh[b*x1] + 
   c[4]*Cosh[b*x1];
W[2] = c[5]*Sin[b*(x1 - z[1])] + c[6]*Cos[b*(x1 - z[1])] + 
   c[7]*Sinh[b*(x1 - z[1])] + c[8]*Cosh[b*(x1 - z[1])];
W[3] = c[9]*Sin[b*(x1 - z[2])] + c[10]*Cos[b*(x1 - z[2])] + 
   c[11]*Sinh[b*(x1 - z[2])] + c[12]*Cosh[b*(x1 - z[2])];
w = Piecewise[{{W[1], x1 <= z[1]}, {W[2], z[1] <= x1 <= z[2]}, {W[3], 
     x1 >= z[2]}}];

(*CANTIL1EVER BC*)
boundary[i_, j_] := 
 Module[ {bc}, 
  bc1 = {W[i] /. {x1 -> 0}, (D[W[i], {x1, 2}]) /. {x1 -> 0}, 
    W[j] /. {x1 -> L1}, ((D[W[j], {x1, 2}]) /. {x1 -> L1})}; bc = bc1]

countinuity[i_, j_] := 
 Module[{eq}, 
  eq1 = {((W[i] /. x1 -> z[i]) - (W[j] /. 
        x1 -> z[i])), (((D[W[i], {x1}]) /. 
        x1 -> z[i]) - ((D[W[j], {x1}]) /. 
        x1 -> z[i])), (((D[W[i], {x1, 2}]) /. 
        x1 -> z[i]) - ((D[W[j], {x1, 2}]) /. 
        x1 -> z[i])), (((D[W[i], {x1, 3}]) /. 
         x1 -> z[i]) - ((D[W[j], {x1, 3}]) /. x1 -> z[i])) + (K[i]*
        W[i] /. x1 -> z[i])}; eq = eq1 ]

e1 = boundary[1, 3];
e2 = countinuity[1, 2];
e3 = countinuity[2, 3];
comb = Tuples[{0, 1*^12}, 3];
eq = Flatten[{e1, e2, e3}];
var = Table[c[i], {i, 1, Length[eq]}];
R = Normal@CoefficientArrays[eq, var][[2]];
R = R /. {K[1] -> K1, K[2] -> K2};
P = FullSimplify[Det[R]];
f[k1_, k2_, beta_] := 
  Module[{m}, K1 = k1; K2 = k2; r = beta; s1 = P; 
   s2 = NSolve[s1 == 0 && 0 < b < 30]; s3 = N[b /. s2]; 
   s4 = s3[[r]]; {uu, ww, vv} = 
    SingularValueDecomposition[R /. b -> s4]; 
   NN = Last[Transpose[vv]];   sub1 = Flatten[{var, b}]; 
   sub2 = Flatten[{NN, s4}];    
   m = w /. Table[sub1[[i]] -> sub2[[i]], {i, 1, Length[sub1]}]; 
   Return[m]];
comb = Tuples[{0, 1*^12}, 2];
g[i_, r_] := 
 Module[{s5}, spring = comb[[i]]; n1 = spring[[1]]; 
  n2 = spring[[2]];  n3 = r; s5 = f[n1, n2, n3]]
beammodes1 = Table[g[i, 1], {i, 1, 2^n}];
beammodes2 = Table[g[i, 2], {i, 1, 2^n}];
beammodes = Flatten[{beammodes1, beammodes2}];
Table[Plot[beammodes[[i]], {x1, 0, L1}, PlotRange -> All], {i, 1, 
  Length[beammodes]}]
kk = {0.000223109, 
   0.000106929, -0.000619179, -0.000534238, -0.000578507, 
   0.000427931, -0.000059498, -0.0000131573, 
   2.28177*10^-8, -2.76837*10^-10, -3.04265*10^-8, 
   3.69151*10^-10, -0.599963, 0.800027};

kk = Chop[kk, 10^-6]
w = Total[Table[kk[[i]]*beammodes[[i]], {i, 1, Length[beammodes]}]]
Plot[w, {x1, 0, L1}]
```

Comment: Check beammodes1 and beammodes2. The last functions do not fulfil  the end condition.

Comment: Yes I evaluated the last functions beammode1 and beammodes2 , the values are not zero but `-0.0000585736` and `-0.000511336` respectively. It is supposed to be zero I am forcing that using the function boundary. I don't know why It is giving results like that.

Comment: Thanks but I am shocked by this new issue.  All the results  I have extracted using this result are wrong. Is there any way to fix it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is caused by the numerical accuracy (or should I say numerical inaccuracy) of machine numbers. If you use accurate numbers (rationalize your numbers), you get for "beammodes:"

[image]

And for the final result:

[image]

Comment: could you please post the modified code here

Comment: How to rationalize the numbers? you mean to say the rationalize the `R` matrix. I did it now still I am getting the same result. could you please post the modified part of the code?

Comment: With rationalize I mean, in your input to change every machine (containing a ".") number to rationalized form. E.g.: given 0.1234, write this as 1234/1000.

Comment: could you please post your code as an answer. I need it, I could not able to solve the issue

Answer (score 0):

Here is my code.

```
ClearAll["Global`*"];
Clear[b]

(*properties of beam*)
Y = 2*^11;
\[Rho] = 7850;
aa = 1/100;
Iyy = 1/10000/12;
L1 = 4;

(*properties of bar*)
\[Gamma] = 2305/1000*L1;

(*Location of the bar*)
z[1] = 15/10;
z[2] = 3;

(*Number of bars*)
n = 2;

W[1] = c[1]*Sin[b*x1] + c[2]*Cos[b*x1] + c[3]*Sinh[b*x1] + 
   c[4]*Cosh[b*x1];
W[2] = c[5]*Sin[b*(x1 - z[1])] + c[6]*Cos[b*(x1 - z[1])] + 
   c[7]*Sinh[b*(x1 - z[1])] + c[8]*Cosh[b*(x1 - z[1])];
W[3] = c[9]*Sin[b*(x1 - z[2])] + c[10]*Cos[b*(x1 - z[2])] + 
   c[11]*Sinh[b*(x1 - z[2])] + c[12]*Cosh[b*(x1 - z[2])];
w = Piecewise[{{W[1], x1 <= z[1]}, {W[2], z[1] <= x1 <= z[2]}, {W[3], 
     x1 >= z[2]}}];

(*CANTIL1EVER BC*)
boundary[i_, j_] := 
 Module[{bc}, 
  bc1 = {W[i] /. {x1 -> 0}, (D[W[i], {x1, 2}]) /. {x1 -> 0}, 
    W[j] /. {x1 -> L1}, ((D[W[j], {x1, 2}]) /. {x1 -> L1})}; bc = bc1]

countinuity[i_, j_] := 
 Module[{eq}, 
  eq1 = {((W[i] /. x1 -> z[i]) - (W[j] /. 
        x1 -> z[i])), (((D[W[i], {x1}]) /. 
        x1 -> z[i]) - ((D[W[j], {x1}]) /. 
        x1 -> z[i])), (((D[W[i], {x1, 2}]) /. 
        x1 -> z[i]) - ((D[W[j], {x1, 2}]) /. 
        x1 -> z[i])), (((D[W[i], {x1, 3}]) /. 
         x1 -> z[i]) - ((D[W[j], {x1, 3}]) /. x1 -> z[i])) + (K[i]*
        W[i] /. x1 -> z[i])}; eq = eq1]

e1 = boundary[1, 3];
e2 = countinuity[1, 2];
e3 = countinuity[2, 3];
comb = Tuples[{0, 1*^12}, 3];
eq = Flatten[{e1, e2, e3}];
var = Table[c[i], {i, 1, Length[eq]}];
R = Normal@CoefficientArrays[eq, var][[2]];
R = R /. {K[1] -> K1, K[2] -> K2};
P = FullSimplify[Det[R]];
f[k1_, k2_, beta_] := Module[{m}, K1 = k1; K2 = k2; r = beta; s1 = P;
   s2 = NSolve[s1 == 0 && 0 < b < 30]; s3 = N[b /. s2];
   s4 = s3[[r]]; {uu, ww, vv} = 
    SingularValueDecomposition[R /. b -> s4];
   NN = Last[Transpose[vv]]; sub1 = Flatten[{var, b}];
   sub2 = Flatten[{NN, s4}];
   m = w /. Table[sub1[[i]] -> sub2[[i]], {i, 1, Length[sub1]}];
   Return[m]];
comb = Tuples[{0, 1*^12}, 2];
g[i_, r_] := Module[{s5}, spring = comb[[i]]; n1 = spring[[1]];
  n2 = spring[[2]]; n3 = r; s5 = f[n1, n2, n3]]
beammodes1 = Table[g[i, 1], {i, 1, 2^n}];
beammodes2 = Table[g[i, 2], {i, 1, 2^n}];
beammodes = Flatten[{beammodes1, beammodes2}];
Table[Plot[beammodes[[i]], {x1, 0, L1}, PlotRange -> All], {i, 1, 
  Length[beammodes]}]
kk = {223109, 106929, -619179, -534238, -578507, 
    427931, -59498, -131573/10, 
    228177*10^-3, -276837*10^-4, -304265*10^-4, 
    369151*10^-6, -599963000, 800027000}/10^9;

kk = Chop[kk, 10^-6]
w = Total[Table[kk[[i]]*beammodes[[i]], {i, 1, Length[beammodes]}]]
Plot[w, {x1, 0, L1}]
```

The beammodes are o.k. but I must have made an error calculating the final result. It is now much smaller (order of 10^-8), hope this is o.k.

The calculations are not done 100% with accurate numbers, because you use NSolve and N. I tried to eliminate these, but then it takes too long.

And here is the output:

[image]

```
{223109/1000000000, 106929/1000000000, -(619179/1000000000), -(267119/
  500000000), -(578507/1000000000), 427931/1000000000, -(29749/
  500000000), -(131573/10000000000), 228177/1000000000000, -(276837/
  10000000000000), -(60853/2000000000000), 369151/1000000000000000, -(
  599963/1000000), 800027/1000000}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Too long means 10 min to get the results?

Comment: Yes I waited approx. 15Min and gave up.

Comment: Thanks daniel.  sorry for the trouble

Comment: I ran  your code. It is also not working

Comment: Version of MMA: 12.1.0 Windows 10. What is not working?

Comment: I run your code in MMA 12 windows 10 I am getting the same result as OP

Comment: What results do you get? I checked once again. With a fresh kernel I copied my code from the forum page and evaluated it. I did in addition add the output after the code. I would be fine, if somebody else could verify that my code is running.